# Login through a fancy secure web form without a UI

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, webtest

I am load testing a product that requires a very secure 2 factor login.
In my load testing tool you only deal with scriptet web traffic, and have no UI, JS or CSS available.

The 3 web forms I need to get through takes the user input, encrypts it - and bakes into something that looks like Base64 - it is then sent by post method. I need to be able to send this data directly from my tool. I have tons of test data, but the login mechanism is a centralized, closed service so I have no insight here.

Is this even possible to get through ? I know in theory I can automate and script anything that flows through the Internet, but I can not see a way here.

I thought about writing a small application that launches before the test, that uses the UI to punch the data, but I'm not even sure this is possible with VS2013 load tests, and considering the incredible amount of logins I need to do this will be a challange.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Record the login sequence (and the whole test case) with Fiddler and study it to see how the login is performed. You could also export the recording to a Visual Studio Web Performance Test.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggesting something - I normally build complex login scripts the way you describe, and by building requests by hand. But this form is special and I'm starting to think this is not doable: The form encrypts the user input on the back-end - there is no visible traffic here and I can not grab it. The next request I see is encrypted beyond recognition

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*The form encrypts the user input on the back-end*". If that means you have web pages that download scripts and do the encryption within the web browser then you have all the code, the challenge is finding the correct pieces and working out how to call them.

Comment: Yes that was poorly written by me. The point is: the encryption process is not visible to be. It is not a client script, and it is not visible web traffic. If it was - hackers would destroy this login easily

Comment: The encryption *must* be done *somewhere*. Unless and until you explain where, in the question, we cannot help you. I think this question is off-topic for Stackoverflow as you are not providing enough details. Please read the help pages about what sort of questions are on-topic.

Comment: Adrian, I am trying to explain: the encryption process is not visible/reachable to the user (me). Obviously it is not, otherwise it would not be very secure, would it ? I am crying out for clever ideas to get AROUND this obstacle. Anyway, thanks for replying, I give up on this entire thing.

Comment: (1) The encryption process must be somewhere, if you cannot explain where it is then there is no way we can guess where it is. (2) Many encryption methods are readily visible in the code, they manipulate the user name and password (plus maybe some other available data) to produce a security value. The is not reversible, ie the username etc is computationally infeasible to extract. But the web site knowing the input username and password etc can create the correct value and compare against the web user's value.